# When click in numeric keyboard close keyboard and put number

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard

I am trying to put the number clicked and close keyboard because just need one number and I don't know how to do it!

< Edited >

I have to put scores for sets, like tennis, and its up to 7 almost, then with one key its enough, I have numeric keyboard, until here perfect, but I would like to click one number and close keyboard with number in editText field.

Comment: `I dont know how to do it!` what exactly you don't know how to do? How to detect the 1 symbol was typed? how to hide keyboard? How to make Android program? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Close keyboard:

```
// Check if no view has focus:
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

And to set the number typed you use the editText´s Listerners

Answer (score 0):

Use a ontextchangedListener for that textfield like the following

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
       int count, int after) {
     }

     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
        //place neccessary logic here and close the keyboard
    }
});
```